# Google Assistant hangs forever now intermittently after receiving successful action responses

Tags: actions-on-google

Coinciding with Google's latest release during Google I/O the other day, I'm finding Google Assistant intermittently hangs with the 3 dots typing animation forever, even after it receives what appears to be an error-free, fast response from my bot.

Usually, when I repeat the utterance, GA gets out of its funk and responds, but not always. It happens both in the simulator and from my Android phone, but more often from outside the simulator.

This never happened before a day ago. Has anyone else noticed this? Is this a known problem? My bot hasn't changed significantly to warrant this kind of erratic behavior at a GA-level. Normally, GA should timeout, not hang showing animation dots.

I have been using Actions SDK V1 on Node, not sure yet if that has something to do with this problem, and should probably migrate to the new SDK.

Comment: Does this happen with other actions, like Number Genie? Could be a bug in the Android app.

Comment: To be clear - this is happening on the phone Assistant? Does it happen with a speaker? (@NickFelker - I had duplicated this on multiple actions and was showing it to people on Thursday.)

Comment: Also to be clear - are you watching the server log to see that you're getting the request and sending a response? Can you also confirm that by looking at the Stackdriver logs in the Cloud Console?

Comment: @NickFelker and Prisoner Just tried Number Genie and doesn't hang there. 
It's happening on Android phone Assistant. I'll have to unpack my speaker as we're leaving on a trip, but we are targeting multi-modal Surface right now. Yes, I receive requests and see responses being sent within 1-2 seconds each, and no obvious errors in my server log. Also looking at Stackdiver logs and nothing unusual. Earlier today this issue subsided, came back and now working again. Intermittent. I am sending Lists usually up to 30 items, and hangs usually occur with list responses. Thanks for help.

Comment: @NickFelker I just found this occur with the "restaurant search" action just after I replied "yes" to its request for permission to access my location. Hung forever.

Comment: I have a Google Actions support engineer looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and migrated my Action to the new Action SDK V2 for Node today and so far I've seen no hang behavior yet after a few hours of testing. It appears as though Google's backward compatibility may not be all there.